# Cómo (reset)los campos de un formulario contenido en un venta modal al salir?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-3

Saludos a toda la comunidad, espero puedan brindarme el apoyo estoy intentando la mejor forma de resetear los campos de un formulario en una ventana modal de bootstrap-3, al oculta el modal.

```
<script >
/*funcion para limpiar formulario contenido en el modal al cerrar la ventame*/
 $('#formulario_resultado_{{object.id}}').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('form').trigger('reset');
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podés usar [`reset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) de javascript así:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* función para limpiar formulario contenido en el modal al cerrar la ventana */
   $('#formulario_resultado_{{object.id}}').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      $(this).find('form').get().reset();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Pruebo de esta forma pero igual no me funciona

Comment: Te  tira algún error en consola?

Comment: NO no arroja error simplemente no lo hace no resetea los campos

Comment: Perdón, probá con `$(this).find('form')[0].reset();`.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar de este modo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#MyModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $(this).find('form').trigger('reset');
      });
</script>
```

Reemplaza `MyModal` con el id de tu modal.

o también puedes hacerlo de este modo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#MyModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $(this)
                .find("input,textarea,select")
                .val('')
                .end()
                .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
                .prop("checked", "")
                .end();
      });
</script>
```